# Bug G-WAN and Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, g-wan

I thought my mistake was [Problems to start G-WAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280713/problems-to-start-g-wan)

but today, I made more testst and my real problem is this:

When I launch an instance with type micro, G-WAN works fine but if i launch the same instance with type small, medium, etc... G-WAN explote!!!

It shows me the errors of the before post.

This is a posible bug between G-wan and Amazon EC2?

anybody knows the solution?

Thanks for all!

Comment: See the G-WAN FAQs related to hypervisors: http://gwan.ch/faq#hypervisors

Comment: Thanks for all the info!! :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems to start G-WAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280713/problems-to-start-g-wan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is:

Newer releases of hypervisors report ZERO CPU, and/or ZERO CPU Core. This is creating a division by zero in G-WAN.

The longer story is:

As G-WAN is optimized for multicore architectures, it uses the CPUID instruction and the OS Kernel structures to find the platform architecture and the associated OS policies (the number of online/allowed CPUs).

In the past, checking the CPUID instruction and the Kernel structures worked well. But today hypervisors have switched to broken CPUID implementations and OS Kernel structures.

This problem created by hypervisors affects hosting companies (VPS servers), and Amazon EC2 instances, as well as companies and end-users.

The other web servers are not affected because users must manually configure, attach and run several server instances for each CPU Core (duplicating the resources that G-WAN uses only once).